# Will "Eliminate ubuntu and re-install it" eliminate all my personal information?

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity

I had Ubuntu 13. 10, but recently I upgraded it to 14. 04 (manualy), compiz started to giving me a lot of problems, now I want to re-install 14. 04, as you know there are many types for installation but I want to know if I choose "Eliminate Ubuntu and re-install it" it will erase all my data, I mean my `/home` partition or just the `/` partition?

Comment: Yes, "Eliminate ubuntu and re-install it" would purge ~/

Answer (score 1):

If, when you installed 13.10, you elected to have everything in one partition, then yes, it will erase your home folder.  The only way your home folder would be safe would be if you have your home folder in its own separate partition.

Answer (score 0):

You said "/home partition", so I'm guessing you mounted /home to a different partition than / (root).  You should be fine.  If you installed / and /home on the same partition, then yes, you will loose all your personal files.

When you're going through the new installation, you'll be able to see your current partitions before commiting to anything.  You'll see what's currently mounted to each partition in the installation partition dialogue.  If you see one with "/home", you're good to go.

You could always use the Deja Dump backup-tool before reinstalling.  It'll save your files and personal settings.  Just be sure to save it to an external media.